# Creating overlapping boxes for mobile view

Tags: html, css, shopify

I am trying to create 2 overlapping boxes as shown in the image below.

[image]

The code is as below:

```css
.fullcolumn {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imagebox55 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.textbox-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 2.5%;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-radius: 20px;
  animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn 5s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn 5s;
}

.textbox-only h3 {
  color: #fcfcfc;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.textbox-only p {
  color: #fcfcfc;
  font-size: 18px;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fullcolumn">
  <div class="imagebox55">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513002749550-c59d786b8e6c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=987&q=80">
  </div>
  <div class=textbox-only>
    <h3>Ariya Ariya Ariya Ariya Ariya Ariya Ariya Ariya </h3>
    <p>Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222 Ariya 222
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything looks okay on desktop view, but when I test it on mobile, the image is cropped in a way that the width becomes smaller, while the height remains. Some of my questions here:

1. How do I make it work in a way that the image could have 100% width and a resized height so that it could be shown fully without any overflow?
2. Is there any way I could make the textbox intersect with the bottom of the image at 50% height of the textbox regardless of the number of words in the textbox?

Meanwhile, if you find any parts of the codes unnecessary in achieving what I would like to do, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: For the textbox position it should work if you set bottom:0; to the absolut positioned textbox and add transform: translateY(50%); which shift the element 50% of it’s own height down

Comment: For the image: it should work if you add a css selector for the image: .imagebox55 img {} and add: width: 100%; height: auto; to it

Comment: @Luckyfella just tried and they work. Thank you so much! Anyway... Another issue here is that the element in this whole section seems to be mixing up with other parts of the website as shown in the image here https://ibb.co/bsMW8XF

May I know how I could get this fixed please?

Comment: When using position absolute the element gets outbof the flow and other element comming after in html don’t ’see’ them. I would prefer to just set the text nearly to bottom of the image and let it ’grow dynamically’ to the top - for mobile devices. Test with max textlength and adjust font-size so it fits into the area. Otherwise (if you want the textbox centered) I think you have to use javascript, get the height of the text and set a gap below the image according to actual text height

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS Code Also you need to add a meta tag into your head section.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .fullcolumn {
    overflow: inherit !important;
}
.imagebox55 img {
    max-height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
}
.textbox-only {
      position: absolute;
    width: 70%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 2.5%;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border-radius: 20px;
   bottom: -100px;
}
}
```